Custom quaternion to Euler giving NaN
I am writing a game + game engine for a college class, and I've decided to store rotations / orientations as quaternions to prevent gimbal lock. The game is a spaceship game with rotational controls, so it would have been a very common problem.
Almost everything works great, however, I'm struggling with converting quaternions back to Euler angles (which I need to do comparisons when interpolating some animations)
Most of the time, this function works correctly. But sometimes, it returns NaN for yaw. I've figured out it's because cosy can end up taking the root of a negative. However, I have no idea how to fix it
Here is the code (compiles with c23, unknown for other standards):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <openGL/openGL.h>

typedef union point_3d {
    GLdouble tab[ 3 ];

    struct {
        GLdouble x;
        GLdouble y;
        GLdouble z;
    };
} point_3d;

typedef struct quaternion {
    GLdouble w, x, y, z;
} quaternion;

point_3d q_to_euler( quaternion q ) {
    point_3d angles;
    GLdouble sinp_cosy = 2 * ( q.w * q.x + q.y * q.z );
    GLdouble cosp_cosy = 1 - 2 * ( q.x * q.x + q.y * q.y );
    angles.x = atan2( sinp_cosy, cosp_cosy );

    GLdouble c = 2 * ( q.w * q.y - q.x * q.z );
    GLdouble siny = sqrt( 1 + c ); // This can be nan
    GLdouble cosy = sqrt( 1 - c );
    angles.y = 2 * atan2( siny, cosy ) - M_PI_2;

    GLdouble sinr_cosy = 2 * ( q.w * q.z + q.x * q.y );
    GLdouble cosr_cosy = 1 - 2 * ( q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z );
    angles.z = atan2( sinr_cosy, cosr_cosy );

    return angles;
}

int main(void) {
    quaternion q = {
        .w = 0x1.6a09e667f3be4p-1,
        .x = 0x0p+0,
        .y = -0x1.6a09e667f3beap-1,
        .z = 0x0p+0,
    };
    point_3d p = q_to_euler(q);
    printf("%a %a %a\n", p.x, p.y, p.z);
    printf( "%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", p.x, p.y, p.z );
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Outputs 3.14 nan 3.14, expected output : 0 ~pi/2 0 (~ means approximately ; in this case it should be a little over pi / 2). I cannot include all the openGL rendering code, but here is how the object looks :

The formulas are adapted from Wikipedia and this article. Please note I'm using openGL's default orientation of axes, so :

y is vertical, pointing up (hence rotation around y is yaw)
x is horizontal, pointing right (hence rotation around x is pitch)
z point out of the screen (hence rotation around z is roll)



Is the quaternion q normalized? 2. Wikipedia has a section on singularities, including a link to here. Does this describe your problem (and solution)? 3. what value for c leads to the NaN? If it's the result of a rounding error (e.g. -1.0000001) you may want to catch this case separately.


How can the problem in this code be caused by a use of cosl when there is no cosl in the source code? Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Use printf with the %a conversion specification to print the exact values of the quaternion members for a failing case. Then write a main routine that initializes a quaternion with those values, passes it to q_to_euler, and prints the results. Edit the question to show that main routine. Show the observed results and the results you expect instead.

@EricPostpischil cosl is an error in renaming, my original variables use the French names for yaw, pitch and roll, and I forgot this one in renaming. This error is now fixed.

@EricPostpischil I will try to provide a minimal working example, however StackOverflow usually complains the question has too much code and refuses to post it when I do that, which is why I now tend to refrain from doing so unless explicitly asked to.

@Yun Yes, every quaternion is normalised in the application. I have tested them at many points, including the start of this function, it never gets a non-normalised input.

This is caused by arithmetic rounding. In general, it is impossible to normalize a quaternion because the exact member values of a normalized quaternion are not representable in a fixed-precision format. The calculations that normalize a quaternion round upward or downward to representable values, so the resulting quaternion will be near normalized but not exactly.
The calculations in q_to_euler also include roundings. In consequence of both of these, sometimes 2 * ( q.w * q.y - q.x * q.z ) will produce a value slightly greater than +2 or slightly less than −2. When it does, simply clamp it to +2 or −2.
